# Starting process in C# doesn't work in all cases

Tags: c#

I can start small programs using this code:

```
if (File.Exists(content[1]))
{
    Process process = new Process();
    try
    {
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = content[1];
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.Start();
        SuccessMessage("Successfully launched " + content[0]);
        //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(content[1]);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ErrorMessage("Couldn't start the process!");
        ErrorMessage(e.Message);
    }
}
```

`content[1]` contains the path to the file.

I can launch for example VLC, but I can't launch Visual Studio with this code. Why?

Comment: Have you checked your permissions level. You many need to set the process as administrator before you can start certain apps.

Comment: Check that VS allow Multiple-Instances! Can you run another instance of MSVS by double Clicking?

Comment: Throws it an exception on VS? If so what is in the exception?

Comment: are you getting an Exception of some sort? use e.ToString() to get more information about the excption...

Comment: If I start visual studio through the console application, it's just saying "Lauching vs...", that code is before the RunItem function(the code in my op is the content of the RunItem function). I can't run 2 instances of Visual Studio 2012, but I can run Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2010 - which didn't work to launch with my program, but it did work to launch normally.

Comment: I tried to run as admin, no difference.

regarding the exception, it seems like it stops somewhere in the RunItem function, since it doesn't say "Couldn't start the process!" or "Successfully launched process", it's just "Attempting to launch process..." which is written before it attempts to process.Start

Comment: You did not read the exception apparently. This should always be the first step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to run your code and got the same problem.
The exception I got was:

```
C:\Users\MyUsername\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication20\Consol
eApplication20\bin\Debug>ConsoleApplication20.exe
Couldn't start the process!System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The requested operation requires elevation
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at ConsoleApplication20.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\MyUsername\Documen
ts\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication20\ConsoleApplication20\Program .cs:line 24
```

This is because of my visual studio is in a high integrity level as you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625957.aspx) 
when I executed the process as an administrator (right click-> run as administrator) the process started. Processes can not start other processes with higher integrity levels without asking for elevation.

Comment: I tried to build my program and run as administrator, but it still wont launch Visual Studio.

Comment: Use this tool to determine in which integrity level your VS runs and in which integrity level your CMD runs. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx